# xcode showing warnings as errors

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ios4

I turned on the setting "Treat Warnings as Errors" used it for a while and then turned it off however warnings still build as errors.  I have restarted xcode and my pc.[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to override this setting on the Target level, rather than Project's.

Comment: didnt realize that you had build options at the target level and at project level.  That is very confusing.  Do you have an example of why that would be useful?

Comment: @odyth it is just a very useful knowledge that target level properties take precedence over project's level. If there are things that you can't explain, try to override 'em for target :) I learnt that the hard way.